# Is it possible to catch/log SignalR Serialization issues?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I've googled quite extensively and have not found an answer to this...

I need to record when messages sent from client to the server hub fail to be deserialized for whatever reason... So much with signalR happens under the covers (well not really... one can easily use chrome/FF developer mode to see what's happening from the clients POV) but I'd like to log serialization failures at the hub..

Anyone implemented something similar?

Comment: Found something here that may help me http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#handleerrors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question... this did help

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#handleerrors

Not quite capturing the errors server side but the error detail returned to the client is much more detailed and allowed me to easily see the type mismatch..

```
var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(hubConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 1):

To log deserialization exceptions on server for messages sent from client to the server you could decorate the DefaultParameterResolver included with SignalR.

Create a decorated IParameterResolver that logs exceptions and calls the DefaultParameterResolver

```
    public class LoggedParameterResolver : IParameterResolver 
    {
       private readonly DefaultParameterResolver _parameterResolver;
       private readonly ILogger _logger;

       public LoggedParameterResolver(DefaultParameterResolver parameterResolver, ILogger logger)
       {
        _parameterResolver = parameterResolver;
        _logger = logger;
       }

       public IList<object> ResolveMethodParameters(MethodDescriptor method, IList<IJsonValue> values)
       {
        try
        {
            return _parameterResolver.ResolveMethodParameters(method, values);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.LogException(exception);
            throw;
        }
      }
    }
```

and configure SignalR to use it

```
IParameterResolver loggedParameterResolver = new LoggedParameterResolver(new DefaultParameterResolver(), logger);
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IParameterResolver),()=> loggedParameterResolver );
```